# SAS9. 3 installation error

Tags: sas

Am unable to install sas 9.3 in my window 10. Am getting below error message

You've attempted to install software intended for one operating system on a
machine using a different operating system. You should either install on a
machine using the operating system you downloaded for or return to the download
site and download the appropriate software

Pls advise how to resolve this problem

Comment: It's off-topic here. Use https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 3):

Your license limits you on what operating systems you can install your SAS distribution. 
If you were to open your software order email, what operating systems are listed there? Alternate, open the SAS license file that you choose during the installation, it should also be listed there.

Answer (score 0):

SAS 9.3 is not compatible with Windows 10. You will not be able to install it natively, and there are no known workarounds. Windows 10 support begins with [9.4M3 and above.](http://support.sas.com/supportos/list?requestAction=summary&outputView=platform&sasrelease=&platformGroup=Windows&platformName=Windows%2010)